# Progressbar: how to create deep copy of original object

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen, runnable, jwindow

I'm trying to use a progress bar similar to this one below in Java:

```
public class MyProgressSplashScreen extends JWindow
{
    private final JProgressBar progressbar;
    private final ExecutorService autoProgressExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    public MyProgressSplashScreen(final int theMin, final int theMax)
    {
        super();
        final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        if (theMin != -1 && theMax != -1)
        {
            progressbar = new JProgressBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, theMin, theMax);
        }
        else
        {
            progressbar = new JProgressBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
            progressbar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        progressbar.setStringPainted(true);
        contentPanel.add(progressbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(contentPanel);
        pack();
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    public void showProgress(final int theValueTo, final int theEstimatedTimeInSeconds)
    {
        showProgress(progressbar.getValue(), theValueTo, theEstimatedTimeInSeconds);
    }

    public void showProgress(final int theValueFrom, final int theValueTo,
            final int theEstimatedTimeInSeconds)
    {
        setVisible(true);
        autoProgressExecutor.execute(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                int numberOfSteps = theValueTo - theValueFrom;
                long timeToWait = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(theEstimatedTimeInSeconds)
                        / numberOfSteps;
                for (int i = theValueFrom; i <= theValueTo; i++)
                {
                    progressbar.setValue(i);
                    try
                    {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(timeToWait);
                    }
                    catch (final InterruptedException e) {   }
                }
                if (progressbar.getValue() == 100) { setVisible(false);  }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am however not able to pass a copy of the MyProgressSplashScreen in order to let a separate thread update the progress.
For instance the program below starts counting from 0 to 10 and then restarts from 0 to 30 while it shouldn't reset to zero!

```
public class TestSplashScreen
{
    private final MyProgressSplashScreen myProgressSplashScreen = new MyProgressSplashScreen(-1,-1);

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestSplashScreen testInvoke = new TestSplashScreen();
        testInvoke.synchronize();
    }

    public void synchronize()
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                myProgressSplashScreen.showProgress(10, 2);
                myProgressSplashScreen.toFront();

                MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
                myRunnable.setSyncProgressSplashScreen(myProgressSplashScreen);
                Thread t1 = new Thread(myRunnable);
                t1.start();
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
    }
}
class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    MyProgressSplashScreen syncProgressSplashScreen;
    public void setSyncProgressSplashScreen(MyProgressSplashScreen syncProgressSplashScreen)
    {
        this.syncProgressSplashScreen = syncProgressSplashScreen;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        syncProgressSplashScreen.showProgress(30, 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you call `syncProgressSplashScreen.showProgress` 2 times. The first time it blocks the thread causing it to increment from 0 to 10 then you call it again going from 0 to 30. Remove the line that reads `myProgressSplashScreen.showProgress(10, 2);` and it wont do it 2 times. Also I noticed you dont set your maximum value for the progress bar so unless you call `myProgressSplashScreen.showProgress(100, 2)` it wont go to 100%.

Comment: I call it two times by design, if you put the two calls to showProgress in the same thread inside the method synchronize() you'll see it correctly updates the progress. Problem is it doesn't if I call it from another thread copying the MySplashScreen object.

Comment: @dendini Why would you call it 2 times?